# Using Dropdown.Button in antd v4

Tags: reactjs, antd

Upgrading from antd v3 to v4 in Dropdown down previously there was overlay option where we can render menu conditionally now it has changed to items which accepts array of objects.

I need help to render options conditionally in Dropdown.Button in the code below using menu. I have commented out menu since it breaks. Thanks.

Codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/loading-antd-5-3-3-forked-lzgpg7?file=/demo.js

```
import "./index.css";
import { DownOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { Dropdown, Space } from "antd";

const items = [
  {
    label: "Submit and continue",
    key: "1"
  }
];

// const menu = (
//   <Menu>
//     {true&& (
//       <Menu.Item  key="1">
//         Option 1
//       </Menu.Item>
//     )}
//     {false && (
//       <Menu.Item
//         key="2"
//       >
//         Option 2
//       </Menu.Item>
//     )}
//   </Menu>
// )

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Space direction="vertical">
      <Dropdown.Button
        icon={<DownOutlined />}
        menu={{
          items
        }}
      >
        Submit
        {/* overlay={menu} */}
      </Dropdown.Button>
    </Space>
  );
};
export default App;
```